# How to compare two different javascript objects for same attributes (without comparing the instance function)

Tags: javascript, class, object, tree, coffeescript

How do I compare the tree structure inside an object task with the obj_after tree, without having to actually compare individual nodes in the tree. (one is an instance of a class i.e. with instance methods and the other has no functions just data).

Please read below to understand my exact problem (not so clear from the above).

I am writing a script that builds a GUI based on a js object tree. I am using coffeescript for this.

I would like to create a class that takes a json, and build the tree.

```
window.GuiTree = class GuiTree
    constructor:(json_GUI_tree)->
```

But the problem I am having is in testing this. I would like to add methods to this class like 'add_node'. That adds a new node to the GuiTree.

So I try this in Jasmine.

```
obj_before =
  1:
    type:"text" 
    name:"task"
    label:"Task"
  2:
    type:"subsection"
    sections:
      3:
        4:
          type:"text" 
          name:"subtask"
          label:"Subtask"   


obj_after =
  1:
    type:"text" 
    name:"task"
    label:"Task"
  2:
    type:"subsection"
    sections:
      3:
        4:
          type:"text" 
          name:"subtask"
          label:"Subtask"   
        5:
          type:"text" 
          name:"subtask"
          label:"Subtask"
```

Where I have added the task 5 to the Gui tree

And I would like to test it like this

```
task = new GuiTree(obj_before)
expect(task.add(3, node_5)).givesNewTree(obj_after)
```

The matcher 'givesNewTree' is a custom matcher.

The problem is here !! how do I compare the tree structure inside the object task with the obj_after tree, without having to actually compare individual nodes in the tree. (one is )

To me it looks like lots of error prone code to write to compare the trees. So I may need to write tests to test. Is there a smarter way.

Comment: Note that you can write: class window.GuiTree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is an implementation of deep equivalence. They're not necessarily error prone, in fact there are several known implementation, the most well known is QUnit's  [deepEqual](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/deepEqual) implementation. [Here's](https://bitbucket.org/pedronis/js-infrastructure/src/e25371d10a62/oejskit/testing_rt/testing-new.js#cl-417) another. Granted it's a quite complicated algorithm.

Your could of course also define a `.equals` (or similarly named) method in your `GuiTree` class that compares two instances in a simpler way based on what you already know is significant about them, but I would try existing deep equal algorithms first since you might be able to import previously written code that you already know is correct.

A hackish alternative is to do `JSON.stringify()` on both objects and expect the resulting `JSON` encoded strings to be equal, but I suspect that could lead to various problems with circular references and the like, but it might get you started.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, The JSON.stringify() seems to be the easiest and works for my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Just today, [Underscore.js 1.2.0](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#changelog) came out, with a new `_.isEqual` function that can handle cycles. Underscore is a robust, mature, and reasonably small library that works in both client-side and server-side JavaScript.